# MSChart Avoid Cursor Replacement when perform Left Mouse Button click is it possible?

Tags: mschart

At MSChart i can drag and move CursorX from left to right when holding Left Mouse Button and drag the mouse, when release Left Mouse Button is stop quit moving the CursorX when a drag of mouse has occured this is nice

But CursorX can be placed anywhere **Also...**
Only by click release Left Mouse Button somewhere at the chartarea,
Cn this feature being turned off or skipped CursorX Replacement when no drag of CursorX has been occured firstly

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved something to avoid Cursor replacement when left mouse button was clicked by toggle of IsUserEnabled for particular cases